# Работа с модификаторами доступа

Tags: java, ооп

Имеется некий абстрактный класс приведенный ниже.

```
abstract class Score{
    private double balance;

    protected String getBalance(String pin){
        if (check(pin))
            return Double.toString(balance);
        return "Введенный пин-код не корректен";
    }
    //баланс для внутренних операций
    protected Double getBalance(){
        return balance;
    }
}
```

Два метода нужны, потому что для ручных операций будет использоваться первый метод (с вводом пин-кода), а для автоматических операций второй (автоматические это например начисление кешбека).

Имеется наследник реализующий следующий функционал

```
public class RegularAccount extends Score{

    public void pay() {
        double price = super.getBalance() * 0.1;
        //TODO
    }
}
```

И все бы ничего, но если создать экземпляр класса `RegularAccount`, то можно вызвать метод `getBalance()` напрямую, чего хотелось бы запретить. Пробовал выносить метод в интерфейс, делать его абстрактным, просто игрался с модификаторами доступа, но все это не помогло или недопустимо.

По логике я предполагаю, что метод `getBalance()` в абстрактном классе должен быть `private`, но как тогда его вызвать из наследника, таким образом, чтобы максимально обезопасить себя?

Есть ли какое-то решение для данной проблемы.

Comment: А в чём принципиальная разница между super.getBalance() и this.getBalance() внутри класса RegularAccount? Рассматривали композицию вместо наследования?

Comment: а как вариант прописи в анонимном классе? (если конечно, не часто будет использоваться этот метод)

Comment: Метод будет использоваться часто. Композицию и анонимный класс не рассматривал, они тут, насколько я знаю, не к чему. Дело именно в модификаторе доступа, т.е. я не должен из мейна получать доступ к методу `getBalance()`

Comment: Непонятно, что вы хотите сделать. Вы хотите, чтоб ваш метод был виден в одних наследника, а вдругих нет или что не так?

Comment: мб тогда интерфейсик создать и имплементировать куда нужно?

Comment: Метод должен быть виден в наследниках, но при этом при создании экземпляра наследника метод не должен вызываться. Интерфейс не подойдет потому так как нельзя обратиться к предку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод с модификатором доступа `protected` доступен из `main` только потому, что  класс, в котором объявлен `main` находится в том же пакете (package) что и `Score`.

Поместите `Score` в отдельный пакет и доступа извне пакета не будет, кроме как у наследников.

Другой, более правильный, способ (а точнее это то, что нужно сделать независимо от правильного разбиения на пакеты) - это не давать клиенту вообще ссылку на конкретную реализацию (`RegularAccount` в вашем случае). Создайте интерфейс с методами, которые должен использовать клиент, и отдавайте клиенту интерфейс. В интерфейсе метода `getBalance` быть не должно, если клиентам его использовать нельзя.

Такой интерфейс имеет смысл поместить ближе к `Score`, т.е. может быть в том же пакете.

Comment: А если у меня есть много наследников, реализующих разные методы, как быть тогда с интерфейсом? И где стоит располагать такой интерфейс в пакете с классом мейн или с остальными файлами?

Comment: Про много наследников ответить сложно, т.к. зависит от их обязанностей и т.д. Тут лучше задать одтельный вопрос. Про интерфейс дополнил ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:
Перекрыть метод `getBalance` в `RegularAccount` с выдачей сообщения что доступ запрещен. используйте метод `getBalance(String pin)`
При этом использование метода предка остается допустимым.

Comment: А как это реализовать?

Comment: Я не знаю точного синтаксиса java. Перекрывать метод может быть неверным решением, если в других методах класса-потомка нельзя использовать вызов метода именно класса предка. Но всегда остается возможность в классе-предке задать модификатор для метода `final`. Вместе с модификатором `protected` это должно дать нужный результат.